# Get a price value based on the number of participants in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to get a price, based on the number of passengers, with a table like this:
(where I only send the number of passengers, example  passanger = 4 paxs, it should return 150000)

```
min   max   price
1     5     150000
6    10     145000
11   15     140000
```

I have tried this :
my Model

```
public function data_harga_paket($peserta)
{
    $this->db->where("minimal_peserta >=", $peserta);
    $this->db->where("maksimal_peserta <=", $peserta);
    $this->db->from('harga');
    return $this->db->get();
}
```

what i want is: if i enter $peserta = 4 , it will return 150000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a CodeIngniter developer, but I mean you have bad conditions.

It should be `minimal <= $peserta, $maximal >= $peserta`, shouldn't?

```
$this->db->where("minimal_peserta <=", $peserta);
$this->db->where("maksimal_peserta >=", $peserta);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for respon my question. I have a price range for a particular participant. And i have participant value, using this value i want to get the price is. For example i have 7 participants, this will return the price = 145000 base on the table above. I confused about the query.

Comment: @hendradev Please read my answer once again and carefully. I think you don't repeat me here what you wrote in question... :-)